# Выполнение действия при завершении обратного отсчета

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, таймер

Код не мой, и мне надо его доработать, чтобы выполнялось определенное действие (открывалась консоль), когда таймер обратного отчета закончит работу

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime as dt


class CountdownLabel(tk.Label):
    """ A Label in the format of HH:MM:SS, that displays counting down from given 
    seconds.
    """

    def __init__(self, master, seconds_left):
        super().__init__(master)
        self._seconds_left = seconds_left
        self._timer_on = False
        self._countdown() # Start counting down immediately

 
    def _start_countdown(self):
        self._stop_countdown()
        self._countdown()
        
        

    def _stop_countdown(self):
        if self._timer_on:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer_on)
            self._timer_on = False
            
    def _countdown(self):
        self['text'] = self._get_timedelta_from_seconds(self._seconds_left)
        if self._seconds_left:
            self._seconds_left -= 1
            self._timer_on = self.after(1000, self._countdown)
            

    @staticmethod
    def _get_timedelta_from_seconds(seconds):
        return dt.timedelta(seconds=seconds)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    countdown = CountdownLabel(root, 3)
    countdown.pack()
    root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.overrideredirect(1)
    root.geometry("300x420+500+200")

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За таймер тут отвечает метод `_countdown`. Он "крутится", пока выполняется условие `if self._seconds_left:` (пока в поле `self._seconds_left` не ноль). Чтобы выполнить действие, когда таймер заканчиваться, нужно к этому `if` добавить блок `else`, пример:

```
def _countdown(self):
    self['text'] = self._get_timedelta_from_seconds(self._seconds_left)
    if self._seconds_left:
        self._seconds_left -= 1
        self._timer_on = self.after(1000, self._countdown)
    else:
        ...  # Сюда пишите действие, которое должно выполниться, когда таймер закончит работу
```